# Integration testing Spring Boot based Microservices

Tags: junit, spring-boot, microservices

I have read many of the guides about working with Spring Boot and RESTful services, and many of them contain information about running unit tests, most notably "Building an Application with Spring Boot".  However, I haven't seen anything that gives an example on how to unit test a Spring Boot application that consumes/depends on other Spring Boot applications, as is common in cloud micro-services architecture. So, for example, we have the following Spring Boot services:

ServiceMediator,
Adapter1,
Adapter2

ServiceMediator calls Adapter1 or Adapter2, depending on the input.

Is there a way to start up the Spring Boot services Adapter1 and Adapter2  before starting and testing the ServiceMediator in a Spring JUnit test?

Comment: Are you talking unit test as to where you would mock the serviceMediator or are you wanting to do an integration test as to where you call the real service?

Comment: Integration testing is what I'm talking about.

Comment: I guess it really depends on how you define it. I'm simply looking for a way to test all services on my local machine in an automated fashion.  Hence, is there a way to start up services the mediator depends on prior to testing the mediator?

Comment: I have found a way to do this, but I don't know if it's the best way.  I'm open to better ways to do it, so please do share if anyone has a better way.  I'm using a ProcessBuilder to start up the adapter prior to testing the mediator.

Answer (score 9):

The [process-exec-maven-plugin](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/maven-process-plugin) could be helpful as allows to start multiple java processes at **pre-integration-test** phase (as standard Spring Boot apps), and it automatically takes care of shutting them down in the **post-integration-test** phase.

**NOTE:** The integration test should be run at the **integration-test** phase for that the **maven-failsafe-plugin** should be configured with **spring-boot-maven-plugin** [see](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/maven-plugin/usage.html). 
Then to run our integration tests **verify** or higher maven Lifecycle should be targeted, because the **integration-test** phase is in fact located between  **package** and **verify** Lifecycles [see Default Lifecycles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

The following maven (pom.xml) configuration worked for me:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>                    
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${integration-tests.skip}</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${integration-tests.skip}</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>           

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${integration-tests.skip}</skip>                  
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>                        
                </execution>                    
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>process-exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
            <executions>                    
                <execution>
                    <id>switchboard-process</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>accounts-service</name>
                        <workingDir>/../../micro-service</workingDir>
                        <waitForInterrupt>false</waitForInterrupt>                          
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>java</argument>
                            <argument>-jar</argument>
                            <argument>${basedir}/../micro-service/target/micro-service-${project.version}-exec.jar</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!--Stop all processes in reverse order-->
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-all</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop-all</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Having an Integration Test class (**WebServerIT**) in **test.java** folder:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = WebServerApp.class)
@WebIntegrationTest("server.port:0")
public class WebServerIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webServerAppContext;

    private MockMvc webServerMockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("the test is set up");
        webServerMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webServerAppContext).build();
    }

    /**
     * This test calls the WebServer's endpoint (/accounts/123456789) which in turn calls the micro-service rest api 
     * which is started using the process-exec-maven-plugin, otherwise the test would fail.
     */
    @Test
    public void testWebServerInteractionWithMicroService() throws Exception {
        this.webServerMockMvc.perform(get("/accounts/123456789"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks promising but do you know if this would work for having Gradle, too?

Answer (score 2):

```
package controller;


import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import mediator.CLPApplication;

import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = CLPApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest()
public class ControllerTest {

    @Value("${adapter.dependency.jar.location}")
    private String adapterDependencyJarLocation;

    @Value("${adapter.dependency.jar.name}")
    private String adapterDependencyJarName;

    @Value("${adapter.url}")
    private String adapterURL;

    @Value("${mediator.url}")
    private String mediatorURL;

    private URL mediator;
    private URL adapter;
    private RestTemplate template;
    Process process = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        adapter = new URL(adapterURL);
        template = new TestRestTemplate();

        //
        // Start the Atomic adapter
        // 
        System.out.println(adapterDependencyJarLocation);
        System.out.println("Starting Adapter");

        try {
            process = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", adapterDependencyJarName)
                .directory(new File(adapterDependencyJarLocation)).start();

            // Try connecting 5 times with a 5 second pause between each
            // to see if it started. 
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                try{
                    System.out.println("Testing to see if Adapter is up");
                    template.getForEntity(adapter.toString(), String.class);
                    System.out.println("Adapter Started");
                    break;
                }
                catch(RestClientException rce){
                    System.out.println("It's not up yet");
                }
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testMediator() throws Exception {
        mediator = new URL(mediatorURL);
        System.out.println("Calling Mediator");
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity(mediator.toString(), String.class);
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        // Getting back JSON, so check to see if it starts with an open bracket
        assertThat(response.getBody(), Matchers.startsWith("{"));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        if(process != null) {
            process.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```