# Is it possible to run integration tests on many spring boot applications at the same time?

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have a gradle project with 3 modules which use spring-boot.
These 3 spring-boot applications are running in parallel and interact with each other.

For example, MODULE1 saves data in MODULE2 and MODULE3 retrieves data from MODULE2 via Rest APIs.

I would like to implement integration tests regarding the interactions between these 3 spring boot applications (ie. have each of them run separately on a different port). Is it possible? how?

I know we can do it for a single spring boot application. ([as explained here](http://www.jayway.com/2014/07/04/integration-testing-a-spring-boot-application/))

Comment: I have tried to do something similar but was not able to. I tried using the spring-boot-maven plugin to start a boot app and then run tests from another module as part of integration-test phase. But the boot app does not run in a separate thread so the build just gets stuck. I have tried the maven-exec plugin again with the same issue. Not sure if there is anything in gradle.

Comment: You can't use `JavaExec` nor `Exec` tasks since they're always waiting for process to finish. What you need is a custom tasks that uses `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: **process-exec-maven-plugin** could be a good option to perform the integration testing of multiple spring-boot application:

You may consider my tested solution for that http://stackoverflow.com/a/37397777/2745810

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever considered using Docker? Like you I've had problem trying to do this and my current solution is to use docker-compose to stand up a container per application. I run each spring boot app in a simple container (*example)*:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/module1.jar app.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

Then I use docker-compose to put it all together:

```
version: '3'
services:
  module1:
    build: ./path/to/module1/Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    links:
     - module2
  module2:
    build: ./path/to/module2/Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "8081:8081"
```

Please note that I haven't tested any of this config as I'm not on a dev machine just now and I've simplified the config to what I think is the bare minimum.