# End to end test across multi Spring Boot applications

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-test, end-to-end

Currently in our project, we are using Spring Integration to integrate many service and some protocol related endpoints.

The project is a multi Spring Boot applications, more than one executable jars will be deployed in production.

The question is:

1. How to run an end to end test which needs to run cross some of these applications, I have to run the one by one manually? In before none-Spring-Boot applications, I can use Maven tomcat7 plugin to complete this work(deploy the wars into an embedded tomcat and run it in **pre-integration-test** phase), now how to start up all related applications before I run my test. Assume I do not use Docker/Vagrant now.

   Similar question found on stackoverflow, [End to end integration test for multiple spring boot applications under Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873548/end-to-end-integration-test-for-multiple-spring-boot-applications-under-maven)

   How to run the end2end test automatically?
2. In an Spring Integration test, sometime I have to mock a http endpoint, so I wrote a simple `Controller` in test package to archive this purpose, but I want to run it at a different port, which make it more like an outside resource.  How to run different `@SpringBootApplicaiton` classes at varied ports at the same time in the test for this purpose?

I am using the latest Maven, Java 8, Spring Boot 1.3.1.RELEASE.

Comment: For the second question, I found Spring provides a `MockRestServiceServer`,  which can mock the target remote REST API to archive this purpose in tests.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Spring Boot comes with the `embedded` Servlet Container support. One of them is exactly Tomcat. The default on for the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web`.

With the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test` and its `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` and `@WebIntegrationTest` you can achieve your requirements, even with the random `port`.

Please, refer to the Spring Boot [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing) for more information:

> To change the port you can add environment properties to @WebIntegrationTest as colon- or equals-separated name-value pairs, e.g. @WebIntegrationTest("server.port:9000"). Additionally you can set the server.port and management.port properties to 0 in order to run your integration tests using random ports.

With that your `@SpringBootApplicaiton` will be deployed to that embedded Tomcat and your test can get access to the ran services/controllers.

Note: it doesn't matter if your Spring Boot application has Spring Integration facilities. The behavior is the same: embedded Servlet Container and integration tests against `@Value("${local.server.port}")`.

Comment: I know well about the `@IntegrationTest` and `@WebIntegrationTest` in Spring Boot applications. Maybe my expression confused you, I am none English guy. What I need is running my standalone end2end test before starts several Spring Boot applications(case 1 in my question).