# Start an already-built module for integration tests of another module

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, multi-module

I have a Maven multi-module project which consists of some library modules and three Spring Boot modules which build on each other's functionality via http[1] access:

`App A  ---http--->  App B  ---http--->  App C`

I'd like to start up an instance of C for the integration tests of B (and of course instances of B and C for the integration tests of A). Maven builds the modules in the right order, so the JARs are available.

**Is there a good (easy) way to start artifacts from other modules in Maven's `pre-integration-test` phase** (and stop them again in `post-integration-test`)?

I don't want to use mocking for this test - that's something for unit tests.

---

[1] Yes, I know it should be https, and it will be https in production, but in development it's only http at the moment.

Comment: Have a look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704842/integration-testing-spring-boot-based-microservices

Comment: For Integration tests you don't need to start the application they can be run within your build by using integration tests via maven-failsafe-plugin named like `*IT.java` like controllerIT etc.

Comment: I would suggest mocking the behavior of App(A/B/C)  as per the need of integration tests. It would save a lot of effort and time in terms of coding and execution.

If your apps are HTTP based try https://www.mock-server.com/proxy/getting_started.html

Comment: Yes, mocking is possible, but the whole point of an integration test is to see how the separate units work when used together, so I don't want to mock anything for this test. I use mocking only for unit tests. I clarified my question.

Comment: @Shadov I use process-exec-maven-plugin which I didn't know before and it works really well - if you want, you may add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.